# Remove commas and make it a string?

Tags: javascript, encryption, string-formatting, caesar-cipher

```
function Cipher(str) { 
    var strArr = [];
    for(i=0;i<str.length+1;i++){
        var unicode = str.charCodeAt(i);
        var ciphUnicode;
        var newStr = String.fromCharCode(ciphUnicode);

        if(unicode>=65 && unicode <=77 )
            ciphUnicode = unicode + 13;
        else if (unicode>=78 && unicode <=90 && unicode!==" ")
           ciphUnicode = unicode - 13;
        else if (unicode === 32)
            ciphUnicode = unicode;
        strArr.push(newStr);
    }
    return strArr.toString();
}
```

`Cipher("GUR DHVPX OEBJA QBT WHZCRQ BIRE GUR YNML SBK.")` should decode to "THE QUICK BROWN DOG JUMPED OVER THE LAZY FOX." but instead I get "T,H,E, ,Q,U,I,C,K, ,B,R,O,W,N, ,D,O,G, ,J,U,M,P,E,D, ,O,V,E,R, ,T,H,E, ,L,A,Z,Y, ,F,O,X,X"

Comment: ```Cipher("GUR DHVPX OEBJA QBT WHZCRQ BIRE GUR YNML SBK.")``` should decode to ```"THE QUICK BROWN DOG JUMPED OVER THE LAZY FOX."``` but instead I get  ```T,H,E, ,Q,U,I,C,K, ,B,R,O,W,N, ,D,O,G, ,J,U,M,P,E,D, ,O,V,E,R, ,T,H,E, ,L,A,Z,Y, ,F,O,X,X```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `strArr.toString()` to `strArr.join('')`.

This joins the strings in the array into a single string. The empty string inside `join('')` ensures there's no commas - the items are each separated by an empty string instead.

Comment: .join, how dumn=b , thats the function I ws looking for and now my code is complete.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
strArr.push(newStr);
```

make strArr into an empty string

```
strArr = "";
```

and change it to

```
strArr += newStr;
```

and you can then remove the .toString on the return.